# How to put progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

How i can put progress bar in my application , i searched but i am getting only for AsyncTask. In below code how to put the progress bar , i am not getting.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
            EditText p1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
             email = e1.getText().toString();
            String password = p1.getText().toString();

            String url = "url"
            AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(main.this);
            mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {

                @Override

                public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {

                    super.callback(url, data, status);

                    String StringData = "" + data;

                        if(StringData.equals("\"S\"")){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("emailid",email );


                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(main.this,"Invalid Combination of Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: What's a Process bar? Do you mean `ProgressBar`?

Comment: yes,sorry for misspelled

Answer (score 0):

you can do as this class

```
public class AQueryAJAXDownload extends Activity {
    // AQuery object
    AQuery aq;
    // Progress Dialog Bar
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    // Mp3 File location
    String url = "http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/jai_ho.mp3";
    // Media player object
    public MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Instantiate AQuery object
        aq = new AQuery(this);
        // Look for button click event using AQuery clicked() method
        aq.id(R.id.btnProgressBar).clicked(this, "downloadSongandPlay");
    }

    // AQuery button click callback method
    public void downloadSongandPlay(View v) {
        // Mp3 file location in SD card
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/pgfolder/jai_ho.mp3");
        // Get SD card location
        File ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // Target location where downloaded file to be stored
        File target = new File(ext, "pgfolder/jai_ho.mp3");

        // Disable button in order to avoid multiple button hits
        aq.id(R.id.btnProgressBar).enabled(false);
        // When Mp3 File exists under SD card
        if (file.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File already exist under SD card, playing Music", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Play Music
            playMusic();
        // If the Music File doesn't exist in SD card (Not yet downloaded)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File doesn't exist under SD Card, downloading Mp3 from Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); // Instantiate Progress Dialog Bar
            prgDialog.setMessage("Downloading MP3 from Internet. Please wait..."); // Set Progress Dialog Bar message
            prgDialog.setIndeterminate(false);  
            prgDialog.setMax(100); // Progress Bar max limit
            prgDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL); // Progress Bar style
            prgDialog.setCancelable(false); // Progress Bar cannot be cancelable
            // Display progress dialog bar and initiate download of Mp3 file
            aq.progress(prgDialog).download(url, target, new AjaxCallback<File>() {
                // Once download is complete
                public void callback(String url, File file, AjaxStatus status) {
                    // If file does exist
                    if (file != null) {
                        playMusic();
                    // If file doesn't exist display error message
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error occured: Status" + status,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected void playMusic(){
        // Read Mp3 file present under SD card
        Uri myUri1 = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/pgfolder/jai_ho.mp3");
        mPlayer  = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(aq.getContext(), myUri1);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                // Start playing the Music file
                mPlayer.start();
                mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Once Music is completed playing, enable the button
                        aq.id(R.id.btnProgressBar).enabled(true);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music completed playing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URI cannot be accessed, permissed needed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Media Player is not in correct state", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IO Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

for more information this link will help yours 
[AQueryAJAXDownload](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/aquery-ajax-callback/)